# Xpages @Author showing 2 Authors

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

I am using the following SSJS:

```
var author = @Author().toString();
var str = author.replace("CN=","");
var str2 = str.replace("O=","");
var str3 = str2.replace("[","");
var str4 = str3.replace("]","");

if("" == str4)
    return @Name("[CN]",session.getEffectiveUserName());
else
    return var4;
```

not the perfect way to do it, but...

**Question:** Why do I get all the users which edited the document in this field? I only want to show the Author of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a list of all users because that's what `@Author()` returns. Here is the description of the function taken from the [online help](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_atfunctions_author_r.html?lang=en): "*Returns the names of the authors of the current document.*"

You can use @Subset() to get the latest author:

```
@Subset(@Author(), -1)
```

and to get the original author:

```
@Subset(@Author(), 1)
```

Use `@Name()` to format the name. So to only show the common name part of the original author, do this:

```
@Name("[CN]",@Subset(@Author(), 1))
```

Comment: And which is the method which returns only the Author?

Comment: I want to get the 1st Author. I do `@Subset(@Author(), 1)` ?

Comment: Do you know a better way to get rid of CN and the [ ] ? Without doing 3 replaces?

Comment: Use @Name("[CN]",@Subset(@Author(), 1))